# Not able to start kong service written in docker-compose

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, kong

I have the following **docker-compose.yml** file to run the **kong** with **postgresql**. I also had the migrations there which I have removed for now. Wondering why is it throwing the connections issue with postgresql.

- The postgresql container is up and running.
- The problem is in the kong

***Here is my docker-compose.yml:***

```
version: '3.2'
networks:
  kong-net:

services:

  kong-database:
    image: postgres:9.5
    container_name: kong-database
    networks:
      - kong-net
    ports:
      - 5435:5435
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=kong
      - POSTGRES_USER=kong
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password

  kong:
    image: kong:latest
    restart: always
    networks:
      - kong-net
    depends_on:
      - kong-database
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
      - 8443:8443
      - 8009:8009
      - 7947:7947
      - 7947:7947/udp
    environment:
      - KONG_DATABASE=postgres
      - KONG_PG_HOST=kong-database
      - KONG_PG_PASSWORD=password
      - KONG_ADMIN_LISTEN=0.0.0.0:8009
```

> I am changing the ports for  kong since some other service is already
>   running in the port 8001

Here is the error logs from `docker-compose logs`

***LOGS:***

```
Attaching to kong_kong_1, kong-database
kong-database    | The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
kong-database    | This user must also own the server process.
kong-database    | 
kong-database    | The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
kong-database    | The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
kong-database    | The default text search configuration will be set to "english".
kong-database    | 
kong-database    | Data page checksums are disabled.
kong-database    | 
kong-database    | fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
kong-database    | creating subdirectories ... ok
kong-database    | selecting default max_connections ... 100
kong-database    | selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
kong-database    | selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
kong-database    | creating configuration files ... ok
kong-database    | creating template1 database in /var/lib/postgresql/data/base/1 ... ok
kong-database    | initializing pg_authid ... ok
kong-database    | initializing dependencies ... ok
kong-database    | creating system views ... ok
kong-database    | loading system objects' descriptions ... ok
kong-database    | creating collations ... ok
kong-database    | creating conversions ... ok
kong-database    | creating dictionaries ... ok
kong-database    | setting privileges on built-in objects ... ok
kong-database    | creating information schema ... ok
kong-database    | loading PL/pgSQL server-side language ... ok
kong-database    | vacuuming database template1 ... ok
kong-database    | copying template1 to template0 ... ok
kong-database    | copying template1 to postgres ... ok
kong_1           | prefix directory /usr/local/kong not found, trying to create it
kong_1           | nginx: [error] init_by_lua error: /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/init.lua:169: [postgres error] could not retrieve server_version: connection refused
kong_1           | stack traceback:
kong_1           |  [C]: in function 'error'
kong_1           |  /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/init.lua:169: in function 'init'
kong_1           |  init_by_lua:3: in main chunk
kong_1           | nginx: [error] init_by_lua error: /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/init.lua:169: [postgres error] could not retrieve server_version: connection refused
kong_1           | stack traceback:
kong_1           |  [C]: in function 'error'
kong_1           |  /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/init.lua:169: in function 'init'
kong_1           |  init_by_lua:3: in main chunk
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first problem is that the `kong` container is starting up before the `kong-database` container has completed its initialization process.  This is the source of the "connection refused" errors.  You can verify this by first starting up the database:

```
docker-compose up kong-database
```

And then waiting until you see:

```
PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.
```

Then in another window, start the `kong` container:

```
docker-compose up kong
```

And you will see a new error:

```
kong_1           | nginx: [warn] [lua] log.lua:63: log(): postgres
  database 'kong' is missing migration: (response-transformer)
  2016-05-04-160000_resp_trans_schema_changes
kong_1           | nginx: [error] init_by_lua error:
  /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/init.lua:172: [postgres error] the
  current database schema does not match this version of Kong.
  Please run `kong migrations up` to update/initialize the database
  schema. Be aware that Kong migrations should only run from a
  single node, and that nodes running migrations concurrently will
  conflict with each other and might corrupt your database schema!
```

This indicates that `kong` is successfully connecting to postgres, but
it looks like you need to run some sort of database schema
initialization before it will work.

A typical solution for this sort of startup dependency is to implement
a wait loop in the startup of your database clients that loops until
the database is available.  Something like:

```
while ! psql -h kong-database -U kong -c 'select 1'; do
  sleep 1
done
```

Comment: but what is the purpose of *depends_on* than. I guess as I have used that the kong has to start only after database is ready right.

Comment: `depends_on` means that the `kong-database` container is *created* before the `kong` container, but Docker has no way of knowing when Postgres is actually ready to service requests.

Comment: Thanks for the  reply I found some solutions like using `depends_on` with `condition` but that is possible only in `docker version2`. which wont match my need as my ultimate goal being to deploy using `docker stack`. I have tried replicating it to deploy using stack and kong service is not running. `task: non-zero exit (1)`

Comment: @TaraPrasadGurung here is a documentation of docker-compose version 3. https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#depends_on . Basically, you need to write your own shell script then wait until your database is up and running then execute kong.